# Convert Android.Graphics.Bitmap to System.Drawing.Bitmap with Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, xamarin.forms

i'm trying to convert a `Android.Graphics.Bitmap` to `System.Drawing.Bitmap`  and vice-versa

My software make a photo with camera and load a Android bitmap with this code:

```
BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(filepath,bmOptions);
```

But i need a `System.drawing.bitmap` in order to process it.
and than i have to re-cast it to Android bitmap.

Can someone help plz?

thank you

Comment: `BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options(); ` You are not using `bmOptions` to begin with.

Comment: System.Drawing.Bitmap is a w32 object and is not available in Xamarin.

Comment: @greenapps   i changed constructor but this not change my problem ... BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();

            Android.Graphics.Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeFile(filepath,bmOptions);

Comment: Of course not.. But your post still keeps that error.